# Kotlin scope function for a mutable map

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

val mValues: MutableMap<String, String> = HashUtil.HashMapInit(30)
This is the map I want to apply scope function on

```
   mValues["name"] = deck.getString("name")
                mValues["desc"] = deck.getString("desc")
                mValues["deckConf"] = deck.getString("conf")
                // general
                mValues["maxAnswerTime"] = mOptions.getString("maxTaken")
                mValues["showAnswerTimer"] = parseTimerValue(mOptions).toString()
                mValues["autoPlayAudio"] = mOptions.getBoolean("autoplay").toString()
                mValues["replayQuestion"] = mOptions.optBoolean("replayq", true).toString()
```

And this code below is what I did but there was a null pointer exception so what is the right way to apply scope function to this mutable map?

```
mValues.apply {
                    set("name", deck.getString("name"))
                    set("desc", deck.getString("desc"))
                    set("deckConf", deck.getString("conf"))
                    // general
                    set("maxAnswerTime", mOptions.getString("maxTaken"))
                    set("showAnswerTimer", parseTimerValue(mOptions).toString())
                    set("autoPlayAudio", mOptions.getBoolean("autoplay").toString())
                    set("replayQuestion", mOptions.optBoolean("replayq", true).toString())
                }
```

Comment: Do you have the stack trace of this exception?

Comment: The scope function's fine, you're probably getting Null Pointer Exception because you're trying to insert *null* into a Map with a non-null value type - i.e. `Map<String, String>` instead of `Map<String, String?>`. All the fetches you're doing where you call `toString()` at the end will turn *null* into the String `"null"`, so it's probably one where you *don't* call `toString()` and the key you're looking for is missing

Comment: Thankyou @cactustictacs you were right there was a null value inserted due to which there was this NPE